# Closing sub-window in tkinter leaves command window behind

Tags: tkinter, window, exit

In the following code if I close by clicking the delete window "X" in the top right of the root window, all is fine.
If I open the sub-window and click "Quit", all is fine.
But if I open the sub-window and click the delete window "X" in the top right of the sub-window, an unresponsive command line window is left behind.

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong, that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
import   tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import *  

def startSubWin():  
    sub_win = Toplevel(root)  
    sub_win.title("Sub Window")  
    ivStopWaiting = IntVar( )  
    btnQuit = Button( sub_win, text="Quit", command=lambda: ivStopWaiting.set(1) )  
    btnQuit.pack( side=tk.LEFT, padx=10 )  
    btnQuit.wait_variable( ivStopWaiting )  
    sub_win.destroy()  
    sub_win.quit()  
    
    
root = tk.Tk()  
root.title( 'Main Window' )  

btnAddOtherTLR = Button( root,text = 'Sub Window', command = startSubWin )  
btnAddOtherTLR.pack( side=tk.LEFT, padx=10 )  

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you close the sub-window by clicking the *"X"* (close) button of the sub-window, the application is still in the `.wait_variable()` loop because the variable is not set yet.

You can use `.wait_window()` instead:

```py
def startSubWin():
    sub_win = Toplevel(root)
    sub_win.title("Sub Window")
    btnQuit = Button( sub_win, text="Quit", command=sub_win.destroy) # destroy toplevel on click
    btnQuit.pack( side=tk.LEFT, padx=10 )
    sub_win.wait_window() # use wait_window() instead of wait_variable()
    sub_win.quit()
```